# React-Native TouchableOpacity is pressable only on the edges

Tags: react-native, expo, touchableopacity

**Using `Expo Go` on iphone**

So I am getting out of my mind and can not solve the problem

**This is my code**

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:"red", borderRadius:20, paddingRight:100, borderWidth:10}}>
        <Text>back</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And when I am pressing at the middle nothing happen, only when I am pressing on the border, also when there is no border the touchable is not pressing at all...

**Using the TouchableOpacity in a custom header

any ideas?

Tried to get rid off the View and etc, nothing helps

Comment: i dont see a reason why it will not work, but you can try to give the style to the TouchableOpacity component (and remove it from the view component).. and check if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, there was a title with absolute position and 100% width which was over the TouchableOpacity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on why your using an inner `<View>`

I tried this locally with the below code and the `onPress` seemingly worked as intended

```js
<View>
<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={() => console.log('test')}
   style={{
     backgroundColor: 'red',
     borderRadius: 20,
     paddingRight: 100,
     borderWidth: 10,
   }}>
      <Text>back</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<View>
```

*Also tested with an empty style attribute, pressing `<Text>` still worked*

Comment: Forgot to mention that i'm using the TouchableOpacity in a custom header :/